# Restrict home directory from showing all the accounts

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

When I run the following code in one of the website on my CentOS 7 box.

```
$directories = glob($somePath . '/home/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
var_dump( $directories );
```

The code above list all the accounts that's in the server.

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "/home/example1"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "/home/example2"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "/home/example3"
}
```

How can I restrict that ONLY the account where the website is hosted is listed. In my case /home/example2 should be listed ONLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the `r` bit for the group 'others' and make root:root owner of the */home* folder, noone can read the directory and thus list all the subdirectories or files in the */home* directory. That means you can't even see your own home directory. You need to leave the execute bit (`x`) in place however so that a user can `cd` into the folder. You can only `cd` into a subfolder when you know its name (and have `x` permission on that folder).

Comment: I would suggest not using /home to host a website. I understand there can be individual needs that may point to this as a good idea, but now to you are trying to change fundamental system design standards to make your non-standard web solution work in a particular way. I usually use symbolic links for files that are not in the typical webroot, if it's not a high security system.

Comment: Nice one. But one could still use `getent passwd` to list user information.

Comment: @0xSheepdog: Agreed but I provided a possible solution to his question. Also, from his question I do not conclude that his website is being hosted in a subfolder of the _/home/_ directory but that he can access it eitherway. The user executing his php script has `rx` access to the _/home_ folder. That should indeed not be the case but by default all users have accesss to that folder.

Comment: Sorry Tom, commenting on mobile app... Meant to comment on the original post. I'll fix when I get home on a PC.